# How To Add The Details in MessageBox?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

How To Add The Details in MessageBox? eg: i link to forms after fillin the second form i want a messagebox showing the details entered by da user and to b shown in messagebox

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand.. Anyway, in a MessagBox you can show any string (message) you please... so, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new form and show it as a modal dialog using `Form.ShowDialog()`. Not messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show) is a list of all posible way to form a MessageBox...

But I think that for your need you should just create a form, that get as parameter all info that you want to display and then call it

```
wanabemb wanabemb = new wanabemb(string info_here);
wanabemb.Show(); //or wanabemb.ShowDialog();
```